# MySQL trigger to update specific row in another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

This is my first attempt at creating a trigger so any help would really be appreciated. I have two tables that look like this:

likes(username, comment_id)
user(username, password, points)

I am trying to create a trigger such that when a user likes a comment (new entry in likes), the point value for that user is incremented by 1. This is what I have attempted:

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger update_points
after insert on likes
for each row
begin
    SET @username = new.username;
    UPDATE user
    SET points = points + 1
    WHERE username = @username

end$$
```

I keep getting MySQL errors. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a DELIMITER call at the end. And also a semi-colon:

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger update_points after insert on likes
for each row begin
SET @username = new.username;
UPDATE user SET points = points + 1 WHERE username = @username;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```